# How do I add to a target number using an array of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

How can I add integers to a certain number, using only an integer array? This is what I have so far. I have to do it recursively.

```
public static boolean sumsToTarget(int[] arr, int target){

    return sumsToTarget(arr, target, 0, 0, 0);

}

private static boolean sumsToTarget(int[] arr, int target, int startIndex, int endIndex, int total){
    if(endIndex >= arr.length){
        if(startIndex >= arr.length){
            return false;
        }
        return sumsToTarget(arr, target, startIndex + 1, startIndex + 1, 0);
    }
    total += arr[endIndex];
    if(total == target){
        return true;
    }else if(total >= target){
        return sumsToTarget(arr, target, startIndex, endIndex + 1, total - arr[endIndex]);
    }else{
        return sumsToTarget(arr, target, startIndex+1, startIndex+1, total) || sumsToTarget(arr, target, startIndex, endIndex + 1, total) || sumsToTarget(arr, target, startIndex, endIndex + 2, total);
    }
}
```

This is how I am testing my code.

```
int[] a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

    System.out.println("Should always print out true.");

    try{ System.out.println("1. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(a, 10)==true)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }
    try{ System.out.println("2. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(a, 40)==false)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }
    try{ System.out.println("3. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(a, 17)==true)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }

    int[] b = {-5, 100, 150, 12, 10, 200, 300, -4, 250, 600};
    try{ System.out.println("4. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(b, -5)==true)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }
    try{ System.out.println("5. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(b, 1)==true)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }
    try{ System.out.println("6. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(b, 601)==true)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }
    try{ System.out.println("7. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(b, 0)==false)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }
    try{ System.out.println("8. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(b, 12)==true)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }

    int[] c = {5};
    try{ System.out.println("9. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(c, -5)==false)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }
    try{ System.out.println("10. " + (ProjectTwo.sumsToTarget(c, 5)==true)); } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("failed"); }
```

And this is the output:

Should always print out true.

1. true
2. false
3. true
4. true
5. true
6. true
7. true
8. true
9. true
10. true

Comment: I myself did not understand the problem. What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Add to the target integer using the numbers in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the algorithm. You have a list of values and you want to try every combination of summing them to see if a combination matches your target.

Let's say the number are `1`, `3`, and `7`. All combination would be:

```
      = 0
1     = 1
3     = 3
1+3   = 4
7     = 7
1+7   = 8
3+7   = 10
1+3+7 = 11
```

To use recursion, you'd basically take the first number (`1`), and try with and without that number, by doing the recursive call for the rest of the numbers, and a total-so-far of `0` or `1`.

On the second invocation, you'd try with and without `3`. Since it'd be called with a total-so-far of `0` or `1`, that will end up be a total of 4 level-3 invocations, with a total-so-far of `0`, `3`, `1`, `4`.

And so on.

If the total equals the target, you stop recursion and return `true`, which should stop recursion all the way back up the call stack.

Optional: If the total exceeds the target, you can stop recursion for this combination, because any further recursion would just get further away from the target.

Now try implementing this logic.